# Table cell slide

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been created custom cell named CustomCell with UIVIew class reference and interface with UITableViewCell reference named SlidingCustomCell. In this interface I call CustomCell interface.
I'd like to slide cell when slide event is appeared. To do this I've been created in interface SlidinCustomCell method:

```
-(void)touchesMoved
```

with simple code

```
CGRect frame = cellGroup.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(100, 0);
cellGroup.frame = frame;
```

When I slide first cell everything looks fine, until I scroll down and see that the 9th cell was automatically slided without my interaction. This error occurs for each slided cell. (1. cell auto slides 9. cell, 2. cell auto slides 10.cell etc. ). I've got created 20 table cells.

Comment: ehere are you implementing the slide method...it should be implemented in didselectrowatindexpath method...under begin/end updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your other cells are being slid over is because they're being reused in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You'll want to set a variable in your model to mark when each cell is slid over. Then check every time a cell is created to see if this item actually needs to be slid.

Something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
   //code to create cell here...
   if (thisModelItemNeedsToBeSlidOver)
    {
        [someTableCell slideOverMethod];
    } 
    else
    {
        [someTableCell resetSlideOver];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why cell's are appearing slided even though you havent interacted with them is because they are being **reused**. In `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` verify with your model that the cell is indeed slided and change it to whatever it's suppose to be (slided or not).